# I need to take a dictionary as a parameter for a function and then invert it. The hard part being is that my dictionary has lists as the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here are my lists:

```
a = {'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'cyan'}
b = {'A':[1,1,2,4], 'B':[1,2,5]}
```

Here is the code I have for inversion of the dictionary:

```
def again(dict):
    tuple(value for value in dict)
    result_dict = {}
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if not value in result_dict.keys():
            result_dict[value] = []
        result_dict[value].append(key)

    return result_dict
```

The function works for dictionary labeled "a" but does not work for dictionary "b". This is because dictionary b has an unhashable data type (i.e. a list).

Running the function:

```
again(a)
output --> {'red': ['A'], 'blue': ['B'], 'cyan': ['C']}
```

I am trying to take dictionary "b" and invert it just like with dictionary "a", but I have no clue how to account for the list values with multiple integers, e.g.:

```
{'A' : [1, 1, 2, 4}, 'B' : [1, 2, 5]}
```

would return you:

```
{1 : ['A', 'B'], 2 : ['A', 'B'], 4 : ['A'], 5 : ['B']}
```

Comment: Note `tuple(value for value in dict)` 1. is actually iterating over the _keys_, despite the name; and 2. isn't assigned to anything, so is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You need another for loop to iterate over the value if it is a list.

```
def again(d):
    result = dict()
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for num in value:
                if not num in result:
                    result[num] = list()
                if key not in result[num]:
                    result[num].append(key)
        else:
            if not value in result:
                result[value] = list()
            result[value].append(key)
    return result

>>> again({'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'cyan'})
{'red': ['A'], 'blue': ['B'], 'cyan': ['C']}

>>> again({'A':[1,1,2,4], 'B':[1,2,5]})
{1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 4: ['A'], 5: ['B']}
```

Comment: Now applying it back to the first example gives `{'r': {'A'}, 'e': {'A', 'B'}, 'd': {'A'}, 'b': {'B'}, 'l': {'B'}, 'u': {'B'}, 'c': {'C'}, 'y': {'C'}, 'a': {'C'}, 'n': {'C'}}`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I misunderstood. Thought OP was dealing exclusively with list values. Edited.

Comment: @ not_speshal and @jonsharpe Thank you for your input. Other than saying thank you for being such a great community, I wanted to say that the fixes suggest by not_special worked! I thought that I would have to do a "try" and "except" condition, but your way makes a lot of sense. I apprecate y'alls input and help

Comment: ps. As I get use to the interface and coding hopefully I can post more concise and directed questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using **defaultdict** with **if-else** condition to check if dictionary value is a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def again(d):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v,list):
            temp = list(set([(x,k) for x in v]))
            for x,y in temp:
                res[x].append(y) 
        else:
            res[v].append(k)
    return dict(res)

print(again({'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'cyan'}))
print(again({'A':[1,1,2,4], 'B':[1,2,5]}))
```

Output:

```
{'red': ['A'], 'blue': ['B'], 'cyan': ['C']}
{1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 4: ['A'], 5: ['B']}
```